# dc.js ordinal stacked barchart with two dimensions, getting NaN values and no stacked bar is displayed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js

I'm working on creating a stacked bar chart ([replicating like this](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html)), with CSV data which has 3 columns.
I'm getting the x-axis values displayed but no stacked bar rendered.
I'm having difficulty replicating from the dc.js example mentioned above.

Please see the code [here](https://codepen.io/ssbs/pen/rYBMwo?editors=1010)

This is the data in the CSV:

```
var data = [ {"Name":"Dani","Subject":"Maths","Score":60}, {"Name":"Dani","Subject":"Science","Score":80}, {"Name":"Dani","Subject":"History","Score":70},
{"Name":"Kelly","Subject":"Maths","Score":90}, {"Name":"Kelly","Subject":"Science","Score":100}, {"Name":"Kelly","Subject":"History","Score":55},
{"Name":"Sara","Subject":"Maths","Score":100}, {"Name":"Sara","Subject":"Science","Score":65}, {"Name":"Sara","Subject":"History","Score":60},
{"Name":"James","Subject":"Maths","Score":70}, {"Name":"James","Subject":"Science","Score":80}, {"Name":"James","Subject":"History","Score":90},
{"Name":"Mike","Subject":"Maths","Score":90}, {"Name":"Mike","Subject":"Science","Score":75}, {"Name":"Mike","Subject":"History","Score":80} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some mistakes in your code. Working solution in the hidden snippet below and in this [pen](https://codepen.io/levvsha/pen/BmBOqd).

Firstly, you should define `YDimension` this way:

```
var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduce(
  function reduceAdd(p, d) {
    p[d.Subject] = (p[d.Subject]|| 0) + d.Score;
    return p;
  },
  function reduceRemove(p, d) {
    p[d.Subject] = (p[d.Subject]|| 0) - d.Score;
    return p;
  },
  function reduceInitial() {
    return {};})
```

Here, you count how many scores get peoples for appropriate subject.

Rewrite `sel_stack` function:

```
function sel_stack(subjectName) {
  return function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.value[subjectName];
  };
}
```

Call `chart.stack` function in loop like this:

```
var subjects = ['Maths', 'Science', 'History'];
...
for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length - 1; ++i) {
  chart.stack(
    YDimension,
    subjects[i],
    sel_stack(subjects[i])
  );
}
```

```js
var data = [ {"Name":"Dani","Subject":"Maths","Score":60}, {"Name":"Dani","Subject":"Science","Score":80}, {"Name":"Dani","Subject":"History","Score":70},
{"Name":"Kelly","Subject":"Maths","Score":90}, {"Name":"Kelly","Subject":"Science","Score":100}, {"Name":"Kelly","Subject":"History","Score":55},
{"Name":"Sara","Subject":"Maths","Score":100}, {"Name":"Sara","Subject":"Science","Score":65}, {"Name":"Sara","Subject":"History","Score":60},
{"Name":"James","Subject":"Maths","Score":70}, {"Name":"James","Subject":"Science","Score":80}, {"Name":"James","Subject":"History","Score":90},
{"Name":"Mike","Subject":"Maths","Score":90}, {"Name":"Mike","Subject":"Science","Score":75}, {"Name":"Mike","Subject":"History","Score":80} ];
var subjects = ['Maths', 'Science', 'History'];

var chart = dc.barChart("#test");

data.forEach(function(x) {
  x.Marks = +x.Marks;
});
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Name;});

var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduce(
  function reduceAdd(p, d) {
    p[d.Subject] = (p[d.Subject]|| 0) + d.Score;
    return p;
  },
  function reduceRemove(p, d) {
    p[d.Subject] = (p[d.Subject]|| 0) - d.Score;
    return p;
  },
  function reduceInitial() {
    return {};})

function sel_stack(subjectName) {
  return function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.value[subjectName];
  };
}

chart
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .dimension(XDimension)
  .group(YDimension, "History", sel_stack('History'))
  .transitionDuration(500)
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(XDimension))
  .margins({left: 80, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20})
  .brushOn(false)
  .clipPadding(20)
  .title(function(d) {
  return d.key + '[' + this.layer + ']: ' + d.value[this.layer];
}).renderLabel(true);

chart.legend(dc.legend());

dc.override(chart, 'legendables', function() {
  var items = chart._legendables();
  return items.reverse();
});

for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length - 1; ++i) {
  chart.stack(
    YDimension,
    subjects[i],
    sel_stack(subjects[i])
  );
}

chart.render();
```

```css
.dc-chart path.dc-symbol, .dc-legend g.dc-legend-item.fadeout {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5; }

div.dc-chart {
  float: left; }

.dc-chart rect.bar {
  stroke: none;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .dc-chart rect.bar:hover {
    fill-opacity: .5; }

.dc-chart rect.deselected {
  stroke: none;
  fill: #ccc; }

.dc-chart .pie-slice {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .dc-chart .pie-slice.external {
    fill: #000; }
  .dc-chart .pie-slice :hover, .dc-chart .pie-slice.highlight {
    fill-opacity: .8; }

.dc-chart .pie-path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.4; }

.dc-chart .selected path, .dc-chart .selected circle {
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #ccc;
  fill-opacity: 1; }

.dc-chart .deselected path, .dc-chart .deselected circle {
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: .5;
  fill: #ccc; }

.dc-chart .axis path, .dc-chart .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges; }

.dc-chart .axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif; }

.dc-chart .grid-line, .dc-chart .axis .grid-line, .dc-chart .grid-line line, .dc-chart .axis .grid-line line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  opacity: .5;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges; }

.dc-chart .brush rect.background {
  z-index: -999; }

.dc-chart .brush rect.extent {
  fill: #4682b4;
  fill-opacity: .125; }

.dc-chart .brush .resize path {
  fill: #eee;
  stroke: #666; }

.dc-chart path.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px; }

.dc-chart path.area {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: none; }

.dc-chart path.highlight {
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke-opacity: 1; }

.dc-chart g.state {
  cursor: pointer; }
  .dc-chart g.state :hover {
    fill-opacity: .8; }
  .dc-chart g.state path {
    stroke: #fff; }

.dc-chart g.deselected path {
  fill: #808080; }

.dc-chart g.deselected text {
  display: none; }

.dc-chart g.row rect {
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .dc-chart g.row rect:hover {
    fill-opacity: 0.6; }

.dc-chart g.row text {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer; }

.dc-chart g.dc-tooltip path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #808080;
  stroke-opacity: .8; }

.dc-chart g.county path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: none; }

.dc-chart g.debug rect {
  fill: #00f;
  fill-opacity: .2; }

.dc-chart g.axis text {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none; }

.dc-chart .node {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .dc-chart .node :hover {
    fill-opacity: .8; }

.dc-chart .bubble {
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: 0.6; }

.dc-chart .highlight {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke-opacity: 1; }

.dc-chart .fadeout {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
  stroke-opacity: 0.2; }

.dc-chart .box text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none; }

.dc-chart .box line, .dc-chart .box circle {
  fill: #fff; }

.dc-chart .box rect, .dc-chart .box line, .dc-chart .box circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px; }

.dc-chart .box .center {
  stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; }

.dc-chart .box .outlier {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc; }

.dc-chart .box.deselected {
  opacity: 0.5; }
  .dc-chart .box.deselected .box {
    fill: #ccc; }

.dc-chart .symbol {
  stroke: none; }

.dc-chart .heatmap .box-group.deselected rect {
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  fill: #ccc; }

.dc-chart .heatmap g.axis text {
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: pointer; }

.dc-chart .empty-chart .pie-slice {
  cursor: default; }
  .dc-chart .empty-chart .pie-slice path {
    fill: #fee;
    cursor: default; }

.dc-chart circle.dot {
  stroke: none; }

.dc-data-count {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }
  .dc-data-count .filter-count, .dc-data-count .total-count {
    color: #3182bd;
    font-weight: bold; }

.dc-legend {
  font-size: 11px; }
  .dc-legend .dc-legend-item {
    cursor: pointer; }

.dc-hard .number-display {
  float: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.site44.com/dc3.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id='test'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail Shabrikov. Thanks for pointing out and correcting my wrongness!!